# How to disable Emacs Lisp auto-reformatting?

Tags: emacs, formatting

I absolutely despise that Emacs automatically reformats my `init.el` file. Every time I use the GUI to change a setting, when I look back at my `init.el` file, Emacs has warped all of the formatting I've done on the file (e.g. changing the indentation, moving things onto their own lines, etc.).

How do I disable this functionality?

Comment: Are you talking specifically about the `(custom-set-variables ...)` and/or `(custom-set-faces ...)` parts?  Emacs regenerates those from its internal data structures when it updates them; it's not "reformatting" them so much as *creating* them.  It's not intended that users manually edit those forms.

Answer (score 0):

Your choice is to either avoid the customize GUI altogether (I am not
even sure that is possible because, e.g.,
[packages](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Packages.html)
use them), or put something like this in your [`.emacs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html):

```lisp
(custom-set-variables
 `(custom-file ,(expand-file-name "custom.el" user-emacs-directory)))

(when (file-readable-p custom-file)
  (message "ignoring and deleting `%s'!" custom-file)
  (delete-file custom-file))
```

This will make Emacs write all its custom forms to a file that you
never load and delete whenever you start Emacs.

This also means that you will have to manually move all your
customizations from [`custom-file`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Customizations.html) to your [`.emacs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) yourself.

Comment: Note that you needn't delete the file -- Emacs won't load `custom-file` unless you tell it to, and it's probably more useful to be able to check the auto-written one in order to extract changes from it.